# Get only Whole Words from a .Contains() statement

Tags: c#, .net, contains

I've used .Contains() to find if a sentence contains a specific word however I found something weird:

I wanted to find if the word "hi" was present in a sentence which are as follows:

> The child wanted to play in the mud
>
> Hi there
>
> Hector had a hip problem

```
if(sentence.contains("hi"))
{
   //
}
```

I only want the SECOND sentence to be filtered however all 3 gets filtered since CHILD has a 'hi' in it and hip has a 'hi' in it. How do I use the .Contains() such that only whole words get picked out?

Comment: Since `hi` is a word, just add padding to each side of it, ie: " hi "

Comment: no sir, I need to check if there are letter before it and after it. if it does, don't pick it @DrewKennedy

Comment: That won't find the word at the beginning and ending of the string. I think a simple regular expression is the right answer here.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Charles's answer won't work. Even if I split in to words, child is still child and the condition checks if child contains 'hi'

Comment: `Contains` works only for exact matches but you want something different. You need a regular expression to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could split your sentence into words - you could split at each space and then trim any punctuation.  Then check if any of these words are 'hi':

```
var punctuation = source.Where(Char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray();
var words = sentence.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(punctuation));
var containsHi = words.Contains("hi", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

See a working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AomXWx

Comment: This won't work. Even if I split in to words, child is still child and the condition checks if child contains 'hi'.

Comment: Have you tried it?  It will work - this is checking it a string array contains the value `hi` - i.e. does it contain the *word*  `hi`, not if each word contains `hi`.

Comment: No it won't. This answer refers to `IEnumerable.Contains` not String.Contains. This answer will work even though it isn't as efficient as a regular expression

Comment: This won't work - what if the sentence was "He said, 'Hi, how are you?'" ??

Comment: @Enigmativity That's a valid case - though I had qualified that splitting by space might be naive.  It works for the sample cases.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, mate. It certainly works for the input I provided but for certain other cases sadly it doesn't. Thanks though

Comment: @Earthling I've updated to strip the punctuation and added the broken sample to the demo.  It should work now.

Comment: Brilliant Charles! Which do you think is more efficient? Using this method or a regex?

Comment: Not sure - they best way to check is to measure it.  If this isn't being used thousands of times, I'd pick whichever you think is more readable or that you're more comfortable with as having clear code often trumps micro-optimisations.

Answer (score 32):

Try using Regex:

```
if (Regex.Match(sentence, @"\bhi\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
{
    //
};
```

This works just fine for me on your input text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I'll try this one as well (Y)

Comment: @OffirPe'er - What do you mean? It outputs `True` for me. Doesn't that mean it works?

Comment: @OffirPe'er - But your code is calling `Regex.Match("Hello World", "orld", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` which is clearly a match. If you'd written `Regex.Match("Hello World", @"\borld\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` then it would fail and that would match my answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity my bad, I omitted the `/b` before, now it works as expected. +1

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  It also works for phrases.  So you could check if a "search phrase" in "these are my search phrase today" and it match but not find it in "these are my search phrases today"

Comment: NOTE: the @"\bfind phrase\b"... the "@" sign here is very important.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a Regex solution:

Regex has a [Word Boundary Anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w(v=vs.110).aspx#WordBoundary) using \b

Also, if the search string might come from user input, you might consider escaping the string using [Regex.Escape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx)

This example should filter a list of strings the way you want.

```
string findme = "hi";

string pattern = @"\b" + Regex.Escape(findme) + @"\b";

Regex re = new Regex(pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

List<string> data = new List<string> {
"The child wanted to play in the mud",
"Hi there",
"Hector had a hip problem"
};

var filtered = data.Where(d => re.IsMatch(d));
```

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z3xFUv)

Comment: It's more efficient to create a single Regex object and use `Matches` on each line. Regex object can be reused *and* are thread-safe

Comment: @Panagiotis Good suggestion.  Updated

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I'll try this one as well (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own extension method for string like:

```
static class StringExtension
        {
            public static bool ContainsWord(this string s, string word)
            {
                string[] ar = s.Split(' ');

                foreach (string str in ar)
                {
                    if (str.ToLower() == word.ToLower())
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please note this will not work for strings containing punctuation or line breaks (e.g. "hi, how are you?") Also, it will not pass [The Turkey Test](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/).