# How to search exact record by asp.net web api with help of lamda expresion

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am facing a problem in searching a exact record by LINQ query method in ASP.NET Web API my controller. This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/tblProducts/AllProductbySearch/{SearchText}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<tblProduct>))]
public IHttpActionResult AllProductbySearch(string SearchText)
{
    IEnumerable<tblProduct> tblProduct = db.tblProducts.Where(x=>x.PrdKeyword.Contains(SearchText)).AsEnumerable();

    if (tblProduct == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(tblProduct);
}
```

In this I am searching the record with value have keyword column and getting the result but problem is that it is not giving exact result for example if in database two record have keyword column value like shirt and another have Tshirt

Then if I pass shirt in SearchText or pass tshirt in SearchText it is giving both record while I want one record which exact match with SearchText. Please help me

My updated action method code is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/tblProducts/AllProductbySearch/{SearchText}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<tblProduct>))]
public IHttpActionResult AllProductbySearch(string SearchText)
{
    IEnumerable<tblProduct> tblProduct = db.tblProducts.Where(x => CheckWord(x.PrdKeyword, SearchText)).AsEnumerable(); 
           
    if (tblProduct == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(tblProduct);
}

private bool CheckWord(string source, string searchWord)
{
    var punctuation = source.Where(Char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray();
    var words = source.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(punctuation));

    return words.Contains(searchWord, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

But is throwing the same error - http 500

Comment: Could you please clarify, do you want matching by words or by whole column value? For example if we have rows as:
1: 'Shirt'
2: 'Tshirt'
3: 'Shirt Red'
And search text is 'Shirt', what data should be returned? Only 1st row, or 1st and 3rd?

Comment: Sir I want match with word and it is matching with words but one problem is accur.  By your example if  search text is "shirt" then it is giving all row 1,2,3 because the word "tshirt" have "t" and "shirt" words and my action method is matching with it but i want it will give me only 1 and 3 record  so please help me @KirylKhadanovich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED 2**
Added ToList() - `db.tblProducts.ToList()...`. In this case we retrieve all data from Data Base and filter them in memory. If we don't retrieve all data before filtering .Net tries to create request to SQL with filtration and can't because there are .Net methods as CheckWord().
I think we can get required data without retrieving all table into memory, but don't know how. As variant we should write specific Stored Procedure and use it. Get all into memory is a simplest way (but not faster)

Please, look at this post [Get only Whole Words from a .Contains() statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073799/get-only-whole-words-from-a-contains-statement)

Actually, for your case solution can be:

```
IEnumerable<tblProduct> tblProduct = db.tblProducts.ToList()
    .Where(x => Regex.Match(x.PrdKeyword, $@"\b{SearchText}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

Option 2. Without regexp:

```
public static bool CheckWord(string source, string searchWord) 
{
    if (source == null)
        return false;

    var punctuation = source.Where(Char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray();
    var words = source.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(punctuation));
    return words.Contains(searchWord, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/tblProducts/AllProductbySearch/{SearchText}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<tblProduct>))]
public IHttpActionResult AllProductbySearch(string SearchText)
{
    IEnumerable<tblProduct> tblProduct = db.tblProducts.ToList()
        .Where(x => CheckWord(x.PrdKeyword, SearchText)).AsEnumerable();
    if (tblProduct == null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(tblProduct);
}
```

Sorry, I'm from phone now, there can be mistakes here. Will try it in 3-4 hour

Comment: Sorry sir it is not working and not giving any record i am waiting for 3 hours

Comment: Sorry, my bad. There was wrong first parameter in the method Match. Now changed it to 'x.PrdKeyword'. Please try again. Let me know if there are still problems.

Comment: Same problem no record found sir

Comment: It just returns empty collection?

Comment: Try to materialize data to local variable as:
    `var products = db.tblProducts.ToList();`
And debug this variable, what kind of data contains this list?

Comment: i Check it in browser it is showing error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match Match(System.String, System.String, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","StackTrace":"   at

Comment: and in fiddler it is giving internal sever error 500

Comment: I am going to update my code in question with UPDATE Heading and it is giving same error

Comment: What errors it returns after last update? I mean in the Visual Studio. And try to get all entities from db as: `db.tblProducts.ToList().Where(x => x. ... `
It just to understand what a reason for error.

Comment: Sir now it is giving null error in  var punctuation = source.Where(Char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray(); this line of code

Comment: and after last update is giving error like LINQ query is not recognizing Checkword Method

Comment: Hello, have you tried to add ToList() after tblProducts? Just to understand, maybe problem that data are not materialize

Comment: Sorry for late reply actually i was out of town for some work ,and grateful for your reply ,now in comment you are saying i am updating the answer but i could not find update where is it...? Plz tell me

Comment: Hello, I've added `.ToList()` to materialize data from Db into memory (`IEnumerable<tblProduct> tblProduct = db.tblProducts.ToList() ...`). All other code is the same.

Comment: Now it is giving "System.ArgumentNullException" error in  var punctuation = source.Where(Char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray(); this line of code

Comment: Possible your table has NULL values for PrdKeyword column. Please try to add check for null (answer edited)

Comment: Thanks for your continuous reply @Kiryl Sir ,we finally reach the goal and i got my desired output and its working well ,Its a huge contribution in my Project.Thanks a lot from my side - Akshay tomar(India)

Comment: Nice, glad to hear :)

Comment: how will i connect with you for next time ?

Comment: I think you can use chats https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users
But maybe you need to up a little your reputation. And you can still create a new question.

Comment: Okey, I will join it

Comment: I need your help again that day i did not fully test it now when i test it.I saw it is not giving correct output ,there is two problem in output first when i entered input like"T shirt" is not giving any record while in input "Tshirt" it is giving record and second when i entered input like"white shirt" or "Leather shoe" it is not giving any record while it is giving output when i entered single word like shirt ,tshirt ,shoe,white ,Please help me

Comment: Do I understand right? E.g. DB has value 'Tshirt'
`Input: 'T shirt' => should return 'Tshirt'`
`Input: 'white shirt' => should return 'Tshirt'`

Comment: yes You understand one problem ,but second problem is that E.g. DB have value like 'white tshirt' and 'white shirt' if Input : 'white  tshirt' then it will give first record and if input:'white shirt ' it will give second record

Comment: For second option, when we search by two words you can use option with regex. In example result2 variable - https://dotnetfiddle.net/o7IgUW In the first case it looks like we need remove redundant spaces, but how can we know when do it. It is possible that there are two words like 'white shirt'

Comment: yes i can understand but i want to make a search option like any shopping site like https://www.ebay.com ,How i can make it so tell me some suggestion

Comment: This scenario doesn't look as simple as topic of this question. I think you need some another approach, something like 'key' words (like 'shirt', 'shoes' etc) and identify this in the request and stored data. Or use categories which will be assigned to each position in your DB and again find this categories in the search request. But I didn't implement this logic earlier and believe that there a lot of different approach. You can create new question with more samples which cover all your cases and ask about approaches or links to related topics

Comment: okey i am going to make new question on it and if u got any idea related to it please comment me ......thanks for  your valuable suggestion and your past comment

Comment: Hello i found the way what they are using in their search function, they are using a api called "elasticsearch" ,In gogle i found many result but i am not able to understand how to apply it so can u help me ?

Comment: Sir i need one help ,I want add payment gateway of payumoney in my web application please help me how i can make it possible

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I haven't work with payment systems and elasticsearch. For both cases I need to google and investigate all required information. Sorry, actually I'm even not able to suggest something...

Comment: Okey Thanks for replying I am just making a e-commerce web site so i need it.thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

You are making a simple mistake. You just need to use `.Equals` instead of `.Contains`.

When you use `Contains` .Net will check if the input string is part of the main string. Whereas `Equals` will check for exact match.

```
var mainStr = “long string with Hello World”;
var inputStr = “Hello”; 
var status = mainStr.Contains(inputStr);
// Value of status is `true`
status = mainStr.Equals(inputStr);
// Value of status is `false`
```

So your code should look like this:

```
IEnumerable<tblProduct> tblProduct = db.tblProducts.Where(x=>x.PrdKeyword.Equals(SearchText)).AsEnumerable();
```

.Equals can also help you find exact match with or without having case-sensitive check in force. The single-parameterised method does a Case-Sensitive check whereas the other overridden methods of `.Equals` gives you an opportunity to ignore it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for replying but u could not understand my problem So please read my problem once again