# c# how to use contains for find a word in a sentence

Tags: c#

Sorry for my English, because I'm not native.

I was wondering how I could find a word in a sentence using contains. But only that word, I'll try to explain it below...

`Thou showedest thy true colors once thou knewest the truth. It seems that, just like me, thou also wert pretending to be someone thou wert not.`

```cs
 if (Text.Contains("Show")) Console.WriteLine("True");
```

In this sentence I want to find "show", there's not that word, there's "showedest" instead. So it'd return false, but it returns true. How could I know if the word SHOW and ONLY SHOW, is there?

Comment: That's not how Contains() works.  It returns true because the letters "show" are present.  It's not operating on whole words.  Take a look at this similar question for suggested answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073799/get-only-whole-words-from-a-contains-statement

Comment: Yey, solved... I never thought it would be as easy as adding a space at the beginning and at the end. Thanks!

Comment: @Omar What if the word is at the beginning or end of the sentence, or has a comma after it?

Comment: @Omar, don't just add spaces.  Look at the answers in the linked question. They handle most cases (punctuation, beginning/end of sentence, etc).

Comment: Wo, you guys are right, I didn't even notice about it. Now I'm using the Regex example. Thanks!